# Change value in config file that contains ' with sed

Tags: regex, sed, configuration-files

I want to replace a value in my postgresql.conf with sed, this is the relevant part:

```
#archive_mode = off
#archive_command = 'blah'
```

For setting archive_mode to on I use the following sed command and that works fine:

```
sed -ri "s/#(archive_mode) .*$/\1 = on/" postgresql.conf
```

Now I also want to change the `archive_command` to `'bleh'`. I tried the following command but sed always complains about the `'` character: `sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unknown option to s'`

```
sed -ri "s/#(archive_command) .*$/\1 = 'bleh'/" postgresql.conf
```

I tried escaping the `'` with `\'` but that didn't help, does anybody know how I can get sed to include a ' in my replacement string?

Comment: Because the line was commented in the original file, corrected the example in the question now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `#` symbol.

```
$ sed -r "s/(archive_command) .*$/\1 = 'bleh'/" file
archive_mode = off
archive_command = 'bleh'
```

To do the both.

```
$ sed -r "s/(archive_mode) .*$/\1 = on/;s/(archive_command) .*$/\1 = 'bleh'/" file
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'bleh'
```

Using a different delimiter.

```
$ sed -r "s~(archive_mode) .*$~\1 = on~;s~(archive_command) .*$~\1 = 'bleh'~" file
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'bleh'
```

Comment: Awesome, that works! Now my actual replacement also contains a `/`, eg. `sed -r "s/(archive_command) .*$/\1 = '/bleh'/" file` and sed complains about the / now (which makes sense as it is also the delimiter), how would I go about that?

Comment: use a different delimiter. `#` or `~`

Comment: Perfect, `sed -r "s~(archive_command) .*$~\1 = '/bleh'~" file` worked! Thanks a lot!